# Conditionally add modules with Boost Python

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, boost-python

I am successfully using Boost Python to build a series of Python libraries. These libraries are built conditionally, depending on the settings the user specifies at build time (via CMake).

Now what I would like to do is to merge them all together into a single library, which would contain a series of modules (one per old library) only if they were needed.

So for example, if before I had:

```
A.so # Always built
B.so # Compiled if B was set
C.so # Compiled if C was set
```

Now I'd like to have:

```
MyLib.so # Always built

---

import MyLib

MyLib.A # always works
MyLib.B # works only if MyLib was compiled with B set
MyLib.C # works only if MyLib was compiled with C set
```

I already know how to create namespaces with Boost Python (via class_), but I'm not sure how I could setup the project so that this final result was possible.

With CMake I can conditionally add files to compile, but I don't know how to define the MyLib module in C++ so that I can add parts to it in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

For now I've added some `ifdefs` inside the exporting functions which limit the exports based on defines created in CMake.

It's not bad although I'd have preferred to keep the code clean from this, but for now it's my only solution.